# Google docs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-docs

I am new to rails and I am looking to integrate google docs with an existing rails project. I want to create a new google doc for a user when he clicks on a button. Are there any pre-existing gems for the same? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: there are plenty of gems out there, just search for `google docs ruby`. You can also try Google Drive REST API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at an official google client gem for ruby [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client).
Example of usage from a documentation

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2 # Alias the module
drive = Drive::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = ... # See Googleauth or Signet libraries

# Search for files in Drive (first page only)
files = drive.list_files(q: "title contains 'finances'")
files.items.each do |file|
  puts file.title
end

# Upload a file
metadata = Drive::File.new(title: 'My document')
metadata = drive.insert_file(metadata, upload_source: 'test.txt', content_type: 'text/plain')

# Download a file
drive.get_file(metadata.id, download_dest: '/tmp/myfile.txt')
```